# Команда подключения к MS SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Глупый вопрос ну все же, пытаюсь в приложении подключиться к экземпляру SQL Express

```
"Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=SiteASAM; Integrated Security=True;";
```

**работает**, переношу ПО на другой компьютер и пытаюсь подключиться к похожему экземпляру MSSQL Express уже **не работает**, меняю на эту строку снова **работает**

```
"Data Source=localhost; Initial Catalog=SiteASAM; Integrated Security=True;";
```

возвращаюсь обратно на первый ПК с этой строкой, **не работает**, меняю обратно на

```
"Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=SiteASAM; Integrated Security=True;";
```

**работает**, ЕСТЬ УНИВЕРСАЛЬНЫЙ СПОСОБ ПОДКЛЮЧЕНИЯ К ЭКЗЕМПЛЯРУ SQL Server Express

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, `localhost` и `.` - синонимы. А то, что следует после ``\`` - имя инстанса. Следовательно, на одном из ваших компьютеров экземпляр SqlServer запущен без имени, на другом - с именем. Поэтому ответ в общем случае - нет универсального способа. Именно поэтому строку подключения принято выносить в конфиг: его легко исправить при деплойменте приложения на другой компьютер и т. п.

Comment: как вариант каждый раз создавать новую базу с помощью codeFirst (либо он проверит и если она уже есть, то работать с ней)

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц - в этом случае тоже нужно указать строку подключения. А она заранее неизвестна на другом компьютере.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov если локаль брать, то известна

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц - что за локаль? Приведите пример. Имеется в виду `localdb` или `localhost`? Увы, это не поможет. На другом компьютере инстанс может иметь _любое_ имя.

Comment: Выводите диалоговое окно для подключения к базе данных: https://www.nuget.org/packages/DataConnectionDialog или https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.ConnectionUI как Вам удобней. В первом пакете NuGet присутствует документация и примеры использования. Также можно указать к каким серверам (MS SQL, OLE DB, etc.) можно подключаться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант, использовать WMI. Каждый экземпляр имеет свою службу с именем вида `MSSQL$<instance>` для именованных экземпляров или `MSSQLSERVER` для экземпляра по умолчанию (Документировано здесь: [Использование службы SQL Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/manage-the-database-engine-services?view=sql-server-2017#using-the-sql-server-service)). Это приводит нас к такому коду для получения имени экземпляра:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Management;
//Reference: System.Management

public static IEnumerable<string> GetSqlServers()
{
    var mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher(
        "SELECT Name FROM Win32_Service WHERE Name LIKE 'MSSQL$%' OR Name='MSSQLSERVER'");
    using (mos)
    {
        var moc = mos.Get();
        using (moc)
        {
            foreach (ManagementObject mo in moc)
            {
                string res = mo.Properties["Name"].Value as string;
                if (res == null) continue;

                int index = res.IndexOf('$');
                if (index < 0) yield return "";
                else yield return res.Substring(index + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}

//...

string DataSource = ".\\" + GetSqlServers().First();
```

Comment: Спасибо работает

Answer (score 1):

Замечал, что при установке MS SQL Server'а имя экземпляра различается на разных машинах. В моем случае на одной это было "SQLEXPRESS.1"

Подозреваю, что имена всех экземпляров можно найти в реестре и вывести при старте программы окно выбора. Если экземпляр один, то можно сразу использовать его.

В какой конкретно ветке реестра - не знаю. Вероятнее всего внутри `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft`. Можно поискать строку SQLEXPRESS или изучить документацию.

UPD.

Несколько способов перечислены на английском SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141154/how-can-i-determine-installed-sql-server-instances-and-their-versions